# How to handle different screen size while developing windows phone 7 app

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-7

**I am completely new in windows phone app development. I want to know what is the best way to handle the different screen size while developing apps in windows phone 7.**

Comment: Actually Windows Phone has only one screen resolution 800x480

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comment, WinPhone7 has only one resolution, but to be prepared for the new devices (WinPhone8) you should code something like this:

```
using System.Windows;  
public void GetScreenResolution(out int w, out int h)  
{  

     w = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;  
     h = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is only one screen resolution available: 480x800 (width x height)

Therefore, you develop for just one resolution, and screen size doesn't matter.

With Windows Phone 8, things will change, but there is no public SDK available yet and the Windows Phone 8 technically still doesn't exist for consumers, so you should continue developing for WP7 and 480x800.

Answer (score 0):

Though I've never seen a 480x640 device it says that Windows Phone 8 support following resolutions, `640x480(4:3), 800x480(5:3), 1280x720(16:9) and 1280x768(5:3).`

[Here](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-8-Multiple-Screen-Resolutions.aspx) a wonderful blog post I've found about windows phone 8 screen sizes.